# Team Foundation Server 2015 to 2018 Upgrade Error (Step 909)

Tags: tfs, upgrade, tfs-2015

Trying to upgrade our on-premise server from 2015 to 2018. For some reason I get this message in the error log:

> Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that
>   the instance is specified correctly, that the server that is hosting
>   the database is operational, and that network problems are not
>   blocking communication with the server.

Why would this happen on step 909 only? Previous steps were already manipulating database so if access is the problem why would it error out on this specific step only?

Tried to re-rerun patch again but giving me the same error log.

I opened the Windows Event Viewer and got multiple errors on this event:

> A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the
>   query in resource pool 'internal'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue. Base on the Windows Event error I considered maybe the RAM was the problem. Checked and the server only had 2 GIG RAM.

Pretty weird since TFS alone was saying it was a database server issue. Anyway, upgrading the ram to 4 GIG solved the issue.

Hopefully this can help someone having the same issue.